# Database issue in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

There's a strange problem on my sharepoint website. When I try to give access to a user on home page it detects a different name of that user, say **abc pqr**, and on sites and lists its detects a different name, say **abc def pqr**(middle name added in second name).

When I give access to a user the name is pulled from the active directory. So, I contacted the person who manages active directory to clarify if 2 accounts have been created for the same user in active directory. But this is not the case. I myself checked the active directory and there's only one account of this user and i.e. with the name **abc pqr**.

So, the user is able to access the home page but not the sites.

So my next guess is somewhere in the sharepoint database, this second name exists. But I'm unable to find the user database.

Also, when I tried to access the profile of this user by clicking on abc pqr, I was able to see the profile(my site).

But, when I clicked on abc def pqr I got this error - An unexpected error occurred. Troubleshoot the cases with sharepoint foundation(something like that with a correlation id). - For this I tried to start the profile synchronization but its not starting. I start it and then come back to synchronization page, in the right hand side it still mentions "Profile synchroniztion unavailable."

More info - this user's name was first deleted from  the active directory and then was again added after a few years.

I guess I need to find out the sharepoint access database and there I need to delete this second name because except the homepage all the site, lists, libraries(when I try to give access) are pulling the second name.

can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm too new to sharepoint. So, sorry for the confusion I might have created. And, would love it if somebody explains me as to where is the backend of a sharepoint webste.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried giving permissions using the username instead of the name?
2. If you suspect that there's a duplicate user in your SQL database (Your SP site uses both AD and FBA?), all info about FBA db is found here: http://blog.morg.nl/2011/08/step-by-step-forms-based-authentication-fba-on-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Thanks for replying. My SP site uses active directory to pull user info. And, there's no duplicate name in AD. Also, I tried giving permission using username and name both. I also tried the "Request for access" option. But nothing helped.